# Does anybody have experience with Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7

Has anyone already tried this, anything particulair that I need to be aware of?

Comment: I hope fortune favors the brave :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yep, been running it for a while and I haven't hit any problems yet. Can't say I've use it all day every day, but I've built WPF, WinForms, Web and Console apps with it for testing various things and haven't had any hitches.

I have it on my Dell X1, which is effectively my "NetBook", and it's really pretty rapid. The only glitch I have had at all is some problems with graphics acceleration, but that's down to the Intel driver I'm using being an old XP driver, and it was easily worked around.

Comment: Happy to see positives about Windows 7 !! +1

Answer (score 0):

I've been running it inside a VM in Parallels Desktop 4 on a MacBook Pro. Absolutely no problems to speak of.

(There's no sound in Windows 7 as virtualized through Parallels, which is a known issue — but not very pertinent to the operation of Visual Studio.)

Answer (score 0):

Jeroen,

I've been unable to install the 2008 Team Developer edition - keep getting a permission error.  I was, however, able to insall the 2008 Team Database edition.  I normally install both editions, so am kind of bummed about not getting the Developer edition to install.  Screenshot of the error is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443075/install-vs-2008-team-developer-on-windows-7) if you're curious.

Comment: Have you tried running it as admin (via right click)? Or (permanently) via the compatibility tab in the shortcut properties?

Answer (score 0):

No Problem with team edition, but only using it for web projects.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using it at work since RC1 and have not run into any issues. Have developed a WinForms app, a WebForms site and now working on a MVC project.

Answer (score 0):

I have had zero problems running Visual Studio 2008 Pro on 32 bit and 64 bit editions of Windows 7 for full-time C++ development.

If the application you are developing doesn't behave correctly under UAC you may will need to run the IDE as admin otherwise it won't run correctly under debug (this is the applications problem, not Windows 7 or Visual Studios).

Others seem to have problems with access rights/permissions, this should also be fixable by running the IDE as admin (via right click) or more permanently via the compatibility tab in the shortcut properties. 
I don't know why this happens, is probably related to their particular user account settings.