# Install VS 2008 Team Developer on Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-7

Has anyone successfully installed VS 2008 Team Developer edition on the Windows 7 beta yet?  Every time I try, i get an error about insufficient privileges in C:\Windows\Winsxs.

I was able to install the VS 2008 Team Database edition with no problems, and had thought that maybe installing the Dev edition after the DB edition might take care of the winsxs issue, but still no luck.

[VS Error Message Image http://img152.imageshack.us/img152/7263/snipimagewd8.jpg](http://img152.imageshack.us/img152/7263/snipimagewd8.jpg)

Edit: My install is on the 32 bit version of windows.  Looks like the 64 bit version works - has anyone tried it on 32 bit windows 7?

Edit: I tried turning off UAC, no luck.  Then, tried to install *just* the "team developer tools" portion (since I already had team DB installed) - and got the same error, only this time it includes an "ignore" button.  Clicked ignore, only to get another error with no ignore, this time for C:\Windows\Winsxs\Policies folder.  Only option at that point is to cancel out of the install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i tried installing this on my other laptop, and it installed fine.

Only (software) difference between the 2 laptops was that one had been running for a few days longer, and had all of the windows update patches installed on it.  So, I checked the first laptop that the install failed on, and there were a bunch of Office 2007 updates to install - so installed those and tried the install again.  After the office patches were all in place, the VS 2008 Team Dev install worked.  This still baffles me as to why it gave me such grief for the first couple days.

I just might have to fire up a VM if i get some free time to test this all again to see if that was really what fixed it - seems strange that office patches should block my VS install.

Comment: The file you posted about looks to be associated with the Visual C++ 9.0 runtime; it's possible one of the Office updates installed the version VS was trying to, so it just skipped that file (and didn't encounter the error) the second time around.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've successfully installed it ( Win7 64bit + Dev edition + SP1 + Team Explorer) and not encountered any issues so far.

I might try installing the smallest possible set of features and see if that works.  If it did I would then add features back in 1 by 1.

Comment: Thanks for the info - my machine is running the 32 bit version, wonder if maybe that's my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Might try disabling UAC completely if you haven't already.  Just search User Access Control in the control panel or something and it should show up.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're not running setup in compatibility mode for Windows XP SP2. Because then it will complain that it needs at least Windows XP SP2 to be installed which it cannot find.
Also I couldn't install it from an ISO image mounted with MS Virtual CDROM. The error I got was "Couldn't load sitsetup.dll". Burning the image to a DVD and running setup from there fixed this problem.

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate build 7000, 32bit, English.

Answer (score 0):

I dont mean to sound patronizing, but have you ran the installer as an adminstrator?